# prevent-duplicates is not working with external scanner for file adapter in spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am creating one directory poller with spring integration. But prevent prevent-duplicates="false" is not working with external scanner.

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter
            id="localCSVAdapter"
            channel="csvinputChannel"
            directory="file:${csv.parent.directory}"
            scanner="testScanner"
            auto-startup="${standard.csv.polling.enabled}"
            prevent-duplicates="false">
        <int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="5000"
                    task-executor="pollingExecutor"/>
    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
<task:executor id="pollingExecutor" pool-size="1"/>
    <bean id="testScanner"
          class="org.springframework.integration.file.WatchServiceDirectoryScanner">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="${csv.parent.directory}"/>
        <property name="filter" ref="testFilter"/>
        <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
        <property name="locker">
            <null/>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

It is giving me following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The 'filter' and 'locker' options must be present on the provided external 'scanner': org.springframework.integration.file.WatchServiceDirectoryScanner@2f6e5d3e
                at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392) ~[spring-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.onInit(FileReadingMessageSource.java:256) ~[spring-integration-file-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
                at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(IntegrationObjectSupport.java:155) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
                at org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean.initSource(FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean.java:177) ~[spring-integration-file-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
                at org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean.getObject(FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean.java:111) ~[spring-integration-file-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
                at org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean.getObject(FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean.java:40) ~[spring-integration-file-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
                ... 65 common frames omitted
```

After removing prevent-duplicates="false it's working fine. Can anybody explain me what is root cause and what is solution for this?

Comment: I am using <spring.integration.version>4.2.8.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>

Comment: As you are using an external scanner you need to add that configuration to your scanner instead of the `inbound-channel-adapter`. You will need to add filter (or remove it) from your scanner. Or don't use an external scanner..

Comment: Hey @M.Deinum i am new to spring integration. I have specified filter as well named "testFilter". Then why it is giving me error about locker and filter??

Comment: got my answer i need to specify prevent-duplicates flag in filter.Thanks for your help @M.Deinum.